# Parsing XML, i have no errors, i don't know whats wrong?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, android-asynctask

I am trying to get rss feeds in my `ListView` and then open the description of each list row.i have no idea why my project closes.what am i doing wrong ?

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 // A reference to the local object
private MainActivity local;

/**
 * This method creates main application view
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set reference to this activity
    local = this;

    GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

    // Start download RSS task
    task.execute("http://www.conciencia.net/rss.aspx");

}

private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssAtomItem> > {
    @Override
    protected List<RssAtomItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            // Create RSS reader
            RssAtomReader rssReader = new RssAtomReader(urls[0]);

            // Parse RSS, get items
            return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ITCRssAtomReader", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssAtomItem> result) {

        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<RssAtomItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssAtomItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set list view item click listener
        itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
    }
}

}
```

DetailsActivity.java

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    String title    = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("title");
    String author   = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("author");
    String guid     = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("guid");
    String description  = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("description");


    Log.d("DEBUG", "title:\t" + title);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "author:\t" + author);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "guid:\t" + guid);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "description:\t\t" + description);


    TextView titleTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView);
    TextView titleTV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView2);
    TextView titleTV3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView3);
    TextView titleTV4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView4);


    titleTV.setText(title);
    titleTV2.setText(title);
    titleTV3.setText(title);
    titleTV4.setText(title);


}


}
```

RssAtomItem.java

```
public class RssAtomItem {

private String title;

private String author;

private String guid;

private String description;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getGuid() {
    return guid;
}

public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}

}
```

ListListener.java

```
public class ListListener implements OnItemClickListener {

// List item's reference
List<RssAtomItem> listItems;
// Calling activity reference
Activity activity;

public ListListener(List<RssAtomItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
    listItems = aListItems;
    activity  = anActivity;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(activity, DetailsActivity.class);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getDescription()));

    i.putExtra("title", listItems.get(pos).getTitle());
    i.putExtra("author", listItems.get(pos).getAuthor());
    i.putExtra("guid", listItems.get(pos).getGuid());
    i.putExtra("description", listItems.get(pos).getDescription());

    activity.startActivity(i);

}

}
```

RssAtomParseHandler.java

```
public class RssAtomParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<RssAtomItem> rssItems;

// Used to reference item while parsing
private RssAtomItem currentItem;

// Parsing title indicator
private boolean parsingTitle;
// Parsing link indicator
private boolean parsingContents;
// A buffer for title contents
private StringBuffer currentTitleSb;
// A buffer for content tag contents
private StringBuffer currentContentSb;

public RssAtomParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssAtomItem>();
}

public List<RssAtomItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if ("entry".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssAtomItem();
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;
        currentTitleSb = new StringBuffer();
    } else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingContents = true;
        currentContentSb = new StringBuffer();
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if ("entry".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;

        if (currentItem != null) // There is a title tag for a whole channel present. It is being parsed before the entry tag is present, so we need to check if item is not null
            currentItem.setTitle(currentTitleSb.toString());

    } else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingContents = false;

        if (currentItem != null)
            currentItem.setDescription(currentContentSb.toString());

    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentTitleSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    } else if (parsingContents) {
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentContentSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}

}
```

RssAtomReader.java

```
public class RssAtomReader {

private String rssUrl;

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param rssUrl
 */
public RssAtomReader(String rssUrl) {
    this.rssUrl = rssUrl;
}

/**
 * Get RSS items.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<RssAtomItem> getItems() throws Exception {
    // SAX parse RSS data
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    RssAtomParseHandler handler = new RssAtomParseHandler();

    saxParser.parse(rssUrl, handler);

    return handler.getItems();

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundm"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android1:id="@+id/listMainView"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="590dp"
    android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android1:layout_marginTop="125dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[POST TITLE GOES HERE]"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[POST AUTHOR GOES HERE]"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsTextView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[POST GUID GOES HERE]"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsTextView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[POST DESCRIPTION GOES HERE]"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is what Logcat says:

```
01-14 03:38:55.933: D/gralloc_goldfish(5610): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-14 03:38:56.623: E/(5610): At line 8, column 71: not well-formed (invalid token)
01-14 03:38:56.633: D/AndroidRuntime(5610): Shutting down VM
01-14 03:38:56.633: W/dalvikvm(5610): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at net.con.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:75)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at net.con.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-14 03:38:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is at line 73 of `MainActivity`? Something there is `null`.

Comment: what i saw and its null is :

Comment: private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask ("return null;")

Comment: i got an error if i don't leave it  null

Comment: Because you have to `return` something. But that isn't line 73.

Comment: this is line 73 : itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: The real error is being hidden by the try-catch block. Rethrow the Exception and you will find out what the real error is.

Comment: @rubenlop88 how can i do that,  Rehthrow the Exception ?

Comment: @user3183582 Run the program again and see what the log says for the exception. That is why you usually want to take some action when you catch an exception (display a message, initialize a variable maybe, something).

Comment: i ran it again, i update my original question(just what log cat says)

Comment: Add `throw new RuntimeException(e);` inside the `catch` block instead of the log. See this page for more information on how to handle Exceptions. http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/ specially rules number 1, 3 and 5.

Comment: You've omitted the relevant log entry again.

Comment: i updated the logcat again.

Comment: it looks like im not getting any help here.i mean any solution yet,thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

In your logcat, the following lines tell you what the error is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 01:45:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3181): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So its a `NPE`...something is `null`. The next line after that which references your project tells you where the exception occurs

```
at net.con.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:73)
```

So something is `null` at line 73 of `MainActivity` which is in `onPostExecute()` of `GetRSSDataTask`.

Now that we know how to find the exception and we know that line 73 is

```
itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so you need to see what is `null` and what could cause this exception. If `itcItems` isn't `null`, set a breakpoint and see, then maybe your `adapter` is `null`.

Now that you know how you can read the logcat this will help you to only post the most relevant code. The other classes and xml files aren't necessary in this case since the exception occurs in `MainActivity`. Posting only the most relevant code initially makes it easier to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

your `ArrayAdapter` is giving a `null Pointer Exception` in `setAdapter` while trying to `getCount()`. This is most probably because you did not recieve any values in `result` in `onPostExecute`

EDIT:

`onPostExecute` uses the `result` returned from `doInBackground`, which, in your case returns `null`. this means `result` in `onPostExecute` is `null` , you build an adapter using this `result`, which is `null` , that is why you get a `null pointer exception` when you try to set an `adapter` with `count = 0`. This means that you are getting an `exception` in the `try catch` block and hence it returns `null` instead of returning `rssReader.getItems()`;.

Comment: mmm,got it, and how can i fix that ?

Comment: look what error gets thrown in try catch block by debugging. and post it. then we will try to resolve.

Comment: i ran the project again and i update on my original question what log cat says.

Comment: does Log.e("ITCRssAtomReader", e.getMessage());ever get logged in logcat?